# NHibernate criteria sub query with multiple join

Tags: c#, hibernate, join, subquery, criteria

anyone knows how to make criteria query for a following case?

I have two classes:

```
classA
{
    int Id;
    string name;
    string surname;
    string myproperty;
    classB classbId;
}

classB
{
    int Id;
    string property1value;
    string property2value;
}
```

There is SQL Query:

```
SELECT a0.name,
a0.surname,
(SELECT a2.myproperty from classB b1
inner join classB b2 on b1.property1value= b2.property2value
inner join classA a1 on b1.Id = a1.classbId
inner join classA a2 on b2.Id = a2.classbId
where a1.Id = 7) as subSelect

FROM classA a0
where a0.Id = 7
```

There is a proj defined as:

```
ProjectionList proj = Projections.ProjectionList();
```

What I need, is create something like this:

```
DetachedCriteria subqueryCriteria = DetachedCriteria.For(typeof(???))
.SetProjection(Projections.Property("a2.myproperty"))
?????
?????
```

and then add this to the proj:

```
proj.Add(Projections.SubQuery(subqueryCriteria), "MyProperty");
```

So I can add this to the main query that I have for now:

```
.CreateCriteria<'classA>("a0")
.CreateAlias("classB", "b0", JoinType.InnerJoin)
.SetProjection(proj)
```

Properties name and surname are included by:

```
proj.Add(Projections.Property(name/surname));
```

But it doesn't matter, the problem is: how to translate the subSelect so it could work?
Thank your for any help.